# Updating only one row based on an "or" clause that may return multiple results

Tags: mysql

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I do not want to update more than one record and it is possible that the two initial queries can match two different records.

```
SET @AppID = (SELECT appID FROM employees WHERE ssn = vSSN);

IF @AppID IS NULL THEN
    SET @AppID = (SELECT appID from applications WHERE appDate = vDate);
END IF;

UPDATE applications
SET status = vStatus
WHERE appID = @AppID;
```

Comment: this query will fail if the `select appid ... vdate` query returns multiple rows anyways. you can't assign a result set to a variable - just an individual value.

Comment: It won't - the actual query is more complex - there won't be more than one result. The issue is that both the query on the employees table and the query on the applications table can each return a different result and I only want to update one of them (giving precedence to the one that matches the employees table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COALESCE operator and the UPDATE/REPLACE statement. To be more precise, COALESCE picks the first non-null value out of a comma-separated list.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

First, the UPDATE alternative:

```
UPDATE applications AS app
INNER JOIN (
SELECT COALESCE(employees.appID, applications.appID) AS appID
FROM applications
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees
ON employees.ssn = vSSN
WHERE applications.appDate = vDate
-- do some ordering or filtering if the date is not unique 
LIMIT 1) AS app2
ON app.appID = app2.appID
SET app.status = vStatus
```

Second, the REPLACE alternative. Please note that REPLACE first deletes the old entry and then reinserts the new one. Therefore, employees.appID may not be  a foreign key of applications.appID.

```
REPLACE INTO applications (appID, status)
SELECT COALESCE(employees.appID, app2.appID) AS appIdToModify, vStatus
FROM applications AS app2
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees
ON ssn = vSSN
WHERE app2.appDate = vDate
```

Comment: It is a foreign key, but why can't I just do an update with the COALESCE query as a subquery? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Thanks this makes sense so I'm marking it as my accepted answer. I'm going to test it later. Optimized code FTW!

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE applications SET status = vStatus WHERE appID = @AppID LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as the row to be updated needs to be determined by logical precedence.